# Why are ghost arguments showing up when running application?

Tags: c#, arguments

When running my application I see an argument `--service` being passed in as argument 1 of 1 to the Main() function in the Program.cs file.
[image]

Right-clicking on the project, going to properties, and then getting into my launch profiles I can see there are no arguments added (seen below).
[image]

I'm not sure where this argument is coming from.  I think I might have had it set up on the project properties (non-SDK-style c# project, light theme) before I transitioned the project to an SDK-style c# project to be able to use the new project properties layout (dark).

Reference to the new project properties UI that was introduced to SDK-style c# projects:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/revamped-project-properties-ui/

Any ideas on how I might figure out where these arguments are coming from when debugging?  Any way to clear them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by scanning all the project files for `--service`.  I found that there was still a file called `MyProject.csproj.user` that was left over from before I converted the project to an SDK-style c# project manually.  It seems this file is still being read during runtime but there does not seem to be a way to edit it via visual studio so it was leaving me scratching my head.

The file contained...

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
  <StartArguments>--service</StartArguments>
  <DebuggerFlavor>ProjectDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I just ended up removing the whole file because there was nothing I needed from that file.  If you want you could just edit the file to take out the `Start Arguments` though.